# .htaccess not redirecting?

Tags: php, mysql, html, apache

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z]+) /servers/page.php?name=$1

RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z]+)/new-thread /servers/new-thread.php?name=$1
```

As you can see by the first line, this:

`mydomain.com/s/hello` actually shows me the content of the page `mydomain.com/servers/page.php?name=hello`

and the second line:

`mydomain.com/s/hello/new-thread` **SHOULD** show me the contents of the page: `mydomain.com/servers/new-thread.php?name=hello`,

but when I type the latter URL, I get the contents of the former page.

This means if I type `mydomain.com/s/hello/new-thread`, I get shown the contents as if I typed `mydomain.com/s/hello`. Can someone point out to me why that is? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z]+)/new-thread /servers/new-thread.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^s/([a-zA-Z]+) /servers/page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What does [L] mean, and what does it do?

Comment: @Ken: means don't process any more rules after this line. Without it, the next line simply process the output of the lines that preceded it. If you don't want things to be case-sensitive, you can use `[NC,L]`.